# Prevent duplicates when saving to Plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I managed to successfully save data to a plist (in this case, a bookmark list), but I can't seem to figure out how to prevent the user from saving same data twice. I'm using "moveRowAtIndexPath" to re-order the bookmarks. When there is a duplicate on the list, it causes a crash during sorting. Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)addBookmarkButtonClicked:(id)sender {

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Bookmarks.plist"];
NSMutableArray *bookmarksArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

if (nil == bookmarksArray) {
    bookmarksArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
}

NSMutableDictionary *array = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

[array setObject:gameName.text.self forKey:@"gameName"];
[array setObject:gameRating.text.self forKey:@"gameRating"];

[bookmarksArray addObject:array];
[bookmarksArray writeToFile:plistPath atomically: TRUE];

}
```

Comment: What's the harm if they save it twice? Also, I think it's a bad idea from a code readability standpoint, to call a dictionary "array".

Comment: I just amended my post. It causes a crash when the user change the list order when editing on the bookmark page. Thanks for the code suggestion. I'll make that change.

Comment: What do you mean by "change the list order", and do you get an error message on the crash?

Comment: What is the exact crash? In my opinion, a user should be able to add identical entries without any problems. If they can't do that then you should fix the fundamental design of your model.

Comment: I'm using moveRowAtIndexPath. It throws an exception on some instances during sorting when there are duplicates. 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: index (3) beyond bounds (3)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you add the item to the BookmarksArray you should check if it already exists.
You can do that by looping thorough all the items in the BookmarksArray and compare each item's keys to the new value you're trying to add. Example:

```
BOOL itemExist, sameName, sameRating;
itemExist=NO;
sameName=NO;
sameRating=NO;

For (int i=0, i<[bookmarksArray count], i++) {
    If ([gameName.text isEqualToString:[[bookmarksArray itemAtIndex:i] itemForKey:gameName]]) {
        sameName=YES;
    }
    If ([gameRating.text isEqualToString:[[bookmarksArray itemAtIndex:i] itemForKey:gameRating]]) {
        sameRating=YES;
    }
    if (sameName && sameRating) itemExist=YES;
    sameName=NO;
    sameRating=NO;
}

if (!itemExist) { 
   //item can be added
}
```